# Package Control: Install Package File "<string>", line 1 Package Control: Install Package ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: console, sublimetext2, package-control

I'm trying to install `Emmet` to Sublime as a plugin.

I open the console, and paste in

```
Package Control: Install Package
```

as instructed on the [Emmet page](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Emmet).

However, when I hit enter I get

```
>>> Package Control: Install Package
  File "<string>", line 1
    Package Control: Install Package
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know why this happening and perhaps how to circumvent it?

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to ensure that you have Package Control installed. Check [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2) for instructions.

Once Package Control is installed and you've restarted Sublime, you need to open the Command Palette, not the console. You can use **`Tools -> Command Palette`**, or use the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Windows and Linux, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on OS X). The Command Palette uses a fuzzy search algorithm, so you can either paste in the entire string `Package Control: Install Package`, or just type ***`pci`*** and it will come up. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> once it's highlighted, type in ***`emmet`***, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, and it will install. Please keep in mind that you need to have [`git`](http://git-scm.org) installed on your system and in your `PATH` in order for Package Control to work properly.

Comment: Weird, when I press enter after typing `pci` (which brings up the Package Control option) it just disappears.

Comment: `Git` seems to be set up properly in my `PATH`. It appears as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;` does that make sense?

Comment: @Imray make sure you keep focus on the Sublime window the whole time, and don't click anything. Check the status bar at the bottom of the window for messages, it may take a little while to load the package repository for the first time. Your `git` setup looks good, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You're right! I didn't notice something was going on down there

Comment: (that's what she said)

Answer (score 0):

I would also add my answer as it might be helpful for some future newbies to sublime.
When I would type ctrl + shift + p in Sublime I would get a screen capture instead of command line of an editor.
In order to change that I needed to go to the SnagIt properties to change its hot keys to make a screen capture on Ctrl+shift+alt+p
After that I was able to call the command line in Sublime editor and install Emmet accordingly.